# Django App Not Working After Deployment to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

The App is A Blog Post App That is Working fine Locally But After I Deployed It To Heroku, The App Cannot run. I did more Than a week trying to fix it through the views and models with no success.

[This Is The Error When Trying To Open The App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUnXD.jpg)

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from posts.models import Post, Category
# Create your views here.

import datetime



 def index(request):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    big_slider_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name='Big_Slider')
    news_box_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name='People')

    cote_divoire_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name="Côte d'Ivoire").exclude(position=1)
    block1_big = Post.objects.filter(position=1)

    culture_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name="Culture").exclude(position=2)
    block2_big = Post.objects.filter(position=2)

    sport_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name="Sports").exclude(position=3)
    block3_big = Post.objects.filter(position=3)

    infrast_et_devel_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name="Infrastructures Et Dévelopements")

    context = {
        'now': now,

        'big_slider_list': big_slider_list[:10],
        'news_box_list': news_box_list[:4],

        'cote_divoire_list': cote_divoire_list[:4],
        'block1_big': block1_big[0],

        'culture_list': culture_list[:3],
        'block2_big': block2_big[0],

        'sport_list': sport_list[:3],
        'block3_big': block3_big[0],

        'infrast_et_devel_list': infrast_et_devel_list[:3],

    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

User = get_user_model()


STATUS = (
    (0, "Draft"),
    (1, "Publish")
)

POSITIONS = [
    (0, ' '),
    (1, 'BIG_BLOCK_1'),
    (2, 'BIG_BLOCK_2'),
    (3, 'BIG_BLOCK_3'),
    (4, 'BIG_BLOCK_4'),

]

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_logged_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Category(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_by_tag', args=[self.slug])


class Post(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    position = models.IntegerField(choices=POSITIONS, default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    display_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=8000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
        verbose_name = "All Post"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})





class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

Comment: Hi @lemanou7! You may get more traction if you include the full text of your code/errors in your question. It's far easier to read/copy/paste than looking through links to external sites.

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with the migrations. Your local DB has all the migrations applied, while your Database on Heroku doesn't have the `post` field. Maybe you added/edited the field later so your two DBs are out of sync. Since this seems to be a new project without data it would be easier for you to `heroku reset` your heroku database and `push` the local db to heroku. Here are the instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: Big YES, Everything you said is true! I will follow your advice and come back here.Thanks

Comment: I went to my terminal and enter : heroku run python manage.py makemigrations (after logging to heroku) then heroku run python manage.py migrate. Thanks for helping !